# Does self invoking anonymous function get garbage collected after it run once?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, self-invoking-function

```
(function (){
  let x = "hy"; 
   console.log(x);
})()
```

so the question is that is this function get garbage collected and removed from the memory once it executed and free up the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *function expression* that was invoked will get garbage collected, but it won't be immediately after the function runs - it'll get GC'd only the next time the GC runs, which may well take a few seconds. (This action is mostly invisible to JavaScript, but not entirely, if you use the new WeakRef, see snippet)

```js
const weakRef = (function (){
  // This fn below is the one we'll be examining to see when it gets GCd
  // It's not the IIFE but the behavior is probably similar enough
  const fn = () => {
    let x = "hy"; 
    console.log(x);
  };
  fn();
  return new WeakRef(fn);
})();

const t0 = Date.now();
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  const hasGcd = weakRef.deref() === undefined;
  console.log('hasGcd:', hasGcd, Date.now() - t0);
  if (hasGcd) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 200);
```

The `x` identifier will be GC'd as well, but there's one complication: the logged expression, since it was logged, can still exist (at least as long as the console exists and doesn't get cleared - this is probably up to the implementation). If you created an object and logged it, the object would probably not be GC'd until after the page was refreshed.

Comment: I doubt the function stays around for seconds. It might even have been allocated on the stack.

Comment: See snippet, I'm seeing around 8 seconds for Chrome. It's not *exactly* the same situation but I think it's similar enough, maybe..?

Comment: this actually gives a clear answer for my problem, so it wont stick around, unless i execute the same code again and it wont eat up my memory.